# program laggin once it reads about 30,000 zipcodes

Tags: java, mysql, while-loop

My program is to match the Craigslist US sites and assign zipcode to it from a US zipcode file. First it reads the zipcode file which has US zipcodes and appropriate cities. After reading each entry it checks the source code of craigslist website to find a match of the city. If it finds a match, the program assigns that zipcode to that url and inserts both the URL and zipcde to mySQL database. But once it reads about 30,000 zipcodes, the program lags a lot.

I've included my code that compares the zipcode and if finds a match it inserts to the database:

```
String sql = "SELECT   city, state FROM CRAIGSLIST";
ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery(sql); 

while(rs.next()) {
    String state = rs.getString("state");
    String city = rs.getString("city");
    if((city.equalsIgnoreCase(cityInFile)) && (state.equalsIgnoreCase(stateInFie))){
        sql = "UPDATE CRAIGSLIST "+ " SET zipcode = '"+ZipCode+"' WHERE city = '"+city+"'" ;
        con.createStatement().executeUpdate(sql);
        System.out.println("Found a match!");
        break;                  
    }
}
```

Somebody please help. Thank you

Comment: Can you share the code where you read the file? You really need to store the file contents in a hash table. This is an efficiency issue.

Answer (score 1):

You're linear scanning 30k records to find a single match.

Create a hashtablemap where the cityInFile is the key and the stateInFile is the value. Then loop through the result set, and check each city against the hashtable.

You're doing O(n^2) work in order to find your matches. If you hash the file, you'll reduce the work to O(n) since you're going to be doing n searches in constant time.

```
if hashtable.get(cityInFile).equals(state)
//match found
```

Another solution you could do is to loop through your file and issue an individual query for each cityInFile to check if it exists and then see if the state matches. It would just require you to add a where clause to your SQL statement.

Comment: The thing is I must use database. The project is to show how you would use database to store the data. I'm actually searching the zip code file, and if found a match with the Craigslist URL city, then I will insert into the stack.

Comment: The hash map is only temporary for you to do the look ups more efficiently, if you find a match, you would still update the database. You want to turn the final into a hash table rather than an array of string pairs.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your table CRAIGLIST doesn't have an index by city, so as you add new records the performance degrades because it has to look through all records to find the city.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting all the records in the database each time, try limiting the results to those that match the city and state using a WHERE clause in your SELECT statement:

```
  String sql = "SELECT   city, state FROM CRAIGSLIST " +
                 "WHERE UPPER(city) = '" + cityInFile.toUpperCase() +
                 "', UPPER(state) = '" + stateInFile.ToUppderCase + "'";
```

Comment: I'm not putting all the data in the database. I search the file and if found a match, then only I insert it into the database.

Comment: But you're pulling all the data from the database: String sql = "SELECT   city, state FROM CRAIGSLIST";
ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery(sql);